# switch between text for 5sec or 50 times

Tags: jquery, loops

How would I build a simple text changer with `jQuery`. I have a `<h1> </h1>` on my page and I would like to change text every half a second between two words (yes) and (no). For a period of 5 seconds or for 50 times.

The idea is that the text would rapidly change from yes to No = Yes...No...Yes...No...Yes...No...

```
var i = 0;
while ( i < 100 ) {
    // This block will be executed 100 times.
    $('h1').append("Yes");
    $('h1').append("No");
    i++; // Increment i
}
```

I know that I need to use a counter but I don't know the best way of creating the change.

Comment: Use recursive function, not while.

Comment: 50 times with an interval of 500ms is not 5 seconds, its 25 seconds ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to use `setInterval` which keeps repeating until you clear the interval

```
var text = ["Yes","No"];
var i =0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $('h1').text(text[i%2]);
    i++;
    if(i == 50)
        clearInterval(interval);
},500);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiec/YT2u7/

If you're worried about the potential for errors in the above code (I wouldn't be with something this simple) then you can do a similar thing with `setTimeout` but it requires you to call the function again at the end.

```
var text = ["Yes","No"];
var i =0;

function update(){
    $('h1').text(text[i%2]);
    i++;
    if(i<50)
        setTimeout(update,500);
}

update();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiec/F6z35/

But as I commented

> 50 times with an interval of 500ms is not 5 seconds, its 25 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Use a `interval`

Try this: (http://jsfiddle.net/Yatnw/1/)

**Html**

```
<h1>yes</h1>
```

**Js**

```
var count = 0,timer=0;
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
    var text = ( count % 2 ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    count = count+1;
    timer = timer + 0.5;

    $('h1:first').text( text );

    if( count > 50 || timer >= 5){
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
},500);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that my question wasn't clear enough I will edit it. but it should replace the text always. That it only show one text at time yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a recursive timeout pattern as setInterval methods can introduce uneccesary memory leaks.

```
var count = 0;

(function loopsiloop(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('h1').html(msg(count));

       if(count < 50) {
           ++count;
           loopsiloop();
       }
   }, 500);
})();

msg = function (count) {
    if (count % 2) {
        return 'yes';
    }  else {
        return 'no';
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcyev/

To see why we should use this over the setInterval method please take a look at the jsperf tests here http://jsperf.com/setinterval-vs-recursive-settimeout and for further reading https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=settimeout+vs+setinterval&oq=set&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60j0l3.3488j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=91&espv=210&q=recursive+settimeout+vs+setinterval

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout), and clear it after it end the execution

Code:

```
var timer = null;
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

setTimeout(function () {
    updatetimer()
}, 500)

var updatetimer = function () {

    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 5000) {
        clearTimeout(updatetimer);
        return;
    }

    if (!$('h1').hasClass('yes')) {
        $('h1').append("Yes").addClass('yes');
    } else {
        $('h1').append("No").removeClass('yes');
    }

    timer = setTimeout(updatetimer, 500);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ewe3D/

Alternatively you can use a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) with similar rules.

Code:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 5000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    if (!$('h1').hasClass('yes')) {
        $('h1').append("Yes").addClass('yes');
    } else {
        $('h1').append("No").removeClass('yes');
    }
}, 500);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8hfNp/